ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when trying to tunnel IPv4 https traffic to a caddy server runing on an IPv6-only machine via socat
I have a home server that is only provided a public IPv6 adress. It serves a searxng (dockerized) behind a caddy reverse proxy (also dockerized). Access from the outside if the accessing device has IPv6 connectivity woks fine (via searx.my.domain).
My Caddyfile:
searx.my.domain {
  reverse_proxy http://192.168.178.2:8898
}

I would like to make the instance available from IPv4-only networks. For this I am trying to use socat which runs on a uber.space shared server. I found this guide (https://timurnet.de/blog/devops/setup-port-tunnel-for-ipv6-networks-with-uberspace/) and tried to adjust it to my problem.
So I added a port to my uberspace, assume its 12345.
I then started socat with the following command:
socat -v tcp4-listen:12345,fork,reuseaddr tcp6-connect:searx.my.domain:443
if I now try to browse to https://myname.uber.space:12345 I get
This site can’t provide a secure connection
myname.uber.space sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I also tried pointing socat to google in order to figure out if my socat command is correct (which seems to be the case):
socat -v tcp4-listen:12345,fork,reuseaddr tcp6-connect:google.com:443
In that case I get
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from keckz.uber.space (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

and after skipping the certificate warning I get a google 404 error page
404. That’s an error.

The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

but the connection seems to work.
So do I have a caddy configuration problem here?

The server expects a TLS connection with an server_name (SNI) in the TLS Handshake of searx.my.domain. But if your access the site with https://myname.uber.space:12345 the server_name will be myname.uber.space. There is no configuration for such a server name, hence ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.
You would need to make sure that a) the server can deal with a TLS connection using the specific server_name and b) there is a valid certificate matching the given name. If a) is not matched you get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. If b) is not matched you get NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.

Thank you for your quick reply!
What I don't understand however is why accessing google via https://myname.uber.space:12345 works then. google.com also doesn't have a certificate for that domain.
I wouldn't mind the certificate warning.

meaning: How do I enable my caddy to deal with those requests like google obviously does so that a) matches?

I think I understand that I cannot get rid of ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID easily but that is not a show stopper for me. Even if that error persists, I can skip the certificate warning in my browser and still access the website like in my second test, when I forward to google.
However something seems different compared to forwarding to google when I forward to my homeserver, as I don't get "ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" but "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". This IS a showstopper.

So as @steffen-ullrich points out, I need to make sure that "the server can deal with a TLS connection using the specific server_name" which is "myname.uber.space" in my case. Somehow google.com seems to be able to handle that. How do I do that? Do I need to add a new section to my Caddyfile? This won't work, as a certificate for that domain is already claimed by the forwarding server running socat.

What works is if I add a http entry for the domain myname.uber.space to my caddy. Then I can access the second server. But I'd prefer to have a https connection. Is there a way to have caddy react on that myname.uber.space but give a different certificate, e.g. the one from searx.my.domain?

@TorbenKorx: if it gives a certificate which does not match the name in the URL (i.e. searx.my.domain when URL says myname.uber.space) then you run into situation b), i.e. NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
